# Sidekiq worker flows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, soa, sidekiq

How can I achieve creating pipelines of workers using sidekiq and ruby?
My intention is to achieve something like:

(Worker1) then (Worker2 and Worker3 in parallel after worker1 execution) then (Worker4 after Worker2 and Worker3 execution)

I have tested sidekiq-superworker but it does not fit on my needs because it does not play well when used under a rails engine, also it depends on a database which I want to avoid,
Do you have any suggestion regarding this subject?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's exactly what Batches solves.

http://sidekiq.org/pro/

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Complex-Job-Workflows-with-Batches